# Exclude Element From CSS Class In Div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Is it possible to not apply a css class to a specific element in the class?

For example:

```
<div className="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
    <h3>LinkedIn</h3>
    <a target="_blank" href= {"https://www.linkedin.com"}><img src={linkedin} className={"linkedin"}/></a>
    <p>Please follow my LinkedIn account to get updated on my experiences and skills and join my network!</p>
</div>
```

In this code I would like to exclude the img tag from the container class so the CSS isn't applied to that element. I know I could just make two separate divs of the same class and put the anchor tag in the middle but I want to know if I can do this programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
    div.dummy  :not(a):not(img) {
      background: black;
      color: white;
      font - size: 20 px;
      width:100%;
      height:50px;
      position:relative;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid dummy bg-2 text-center">
      <h3>LinkedIn</h3>
      <a target="_blank" href={ "https://www.linkedin.com"}>
        <img src={linkedin} class={ "linkedin"}/>
        </a>
      <p>Please follow my LinkedIn account to get updated on my experiences and skills and join my network!
      </p>
    </div>
```

You can see in the above demo that except `img` tag, all are getting affected.

Try using `:not` selector

[Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) consulting [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

else have a particular css for the img overriding any css you want.

Answer (score 3):

The`:not(selector) selector matches every element that is NOT the specified element/selector.

```
:not(.container>img) {
       background-color: blue;
       //your css here
    }
```